# jQuery get each div container and the values of sub classes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following html code:

```
<div class="container">
   <input class="class1" value="class1Text" />
   <span class="class2">class2Text</span>                                                                               
</div>

<div class="container">
   <input class="class1" value="class1Text" />
   <span class="class2">class2Text</span>                                                                               
</div>

<div class="container">
   <input class="class1" value="class1Text" />
   <span class="class2">class2Text</span>                                                                               
</div>
```

this is my jQuery code to get each .container:

```
$( ".container" ).each(function() { 
   // DO SOMETHINGS
})
```

But how can I get the the value and text form class1 and class2 of each container?

Comment: what do you mean by `values of sub classes` ?

Comment: `$(".container").find(".class1")`... please google before asking... There are hundreds of results for `how to get children elements`... and `how to get element value` etc... Get in common with a library you're using! Read the available methods for DOM traversal: https://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/ and https://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/tree-traversal/ and https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/traversing/ are just from the jQuery DOCS... **http://api.jquery.com/**

Comment: Your question suggests a lack of searching/trying to find a solution prior to posting. You haven’t attempted a solution which as above shows that you haven’t researched enough (or at all).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need two jQuery method for this.

`.each` - to iterate over every element in array of elements.

`.children` - to fetch the children of current element in iteration.

```js
$(".container").each(function() {
    console.log($(this).children('.class1').val());
    console.log($(this).children('.class2').text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <input class="class1" value="class1Text" />
  <span class="class2">class2Text</span>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <input class="class1" value="class1Text" />
  <span class="class2">class2Text</span>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <input class="class1" value="class1Text" />
  <span class="class2">class2Text</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

By using a combination of `this` and `.find()` like this:

```js
$(".container").each(function() {
  console.log($(this).find('.class1').val());
  console.log($(this).find('.class2').text());
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <input class="class1" value="class1Text" />
  <span class="class2">class2Text</span>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <input class="class1" value="class1Text" />
  <span class="class2">class2Text</span>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <input class="class1" value="class1Text" />
  <span class="class2">class2Text</span>
</div>
```